# how to use EntityFieldQuery by language?

Tags: database

```
global $language;

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->propertyCondition('type', 'events')
->propertyCondition('language', $language->language)
->propertyCondition('tnid', $output)
->execute();
```

I tried using this code and it is showing me empty page, any help on using EntityFieldQuery?

Answer (score 6):

$language variable  is better to be in the function as:

```
 function getListNode(){
   global $language;
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
   $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
         ->entityCondition('bundle', 'content_type', '=')
         ->propertyCondition('language', $language->language, '=');
   $nids = $query->execute();
   return entity_load('node', array_keys($nids['node']));
 }
```

it works for me
good luck

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not actually querying any field values, I'm not really sure why you need to use an `EntityFieldQuery` for this. It would be much easier (and far more efficient) to use a straight query to load the node id(s):

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition('type', 'events')
  ->condition('language', $language->language)
  ->condition('tnid', $output)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();

$matching_nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Comment: what I am trying to achieve in a multilang site, I tried to set language fallback hack using views before I was using entity translations but it's bugy&it can't work well for revisioning of node+translated node.

the case in the views.I'm now using the i18n,it work great for the revisioning node+translations.

is there anyway I can hack the views to load eng content if the translations are not available.

ex :
en : me test 1, me test 2
bur : me test 1, me test 2 burmese

as in bur the"me test 1" is not translated yet, it'll pull en content

can you please help.I've been frustrated for months:(

Comment: @Boby is asking for how to search using EntityFieldQuery, using db_select doesn't answer his actual question

Comment: @PaulSheldrake An `EntityFieldQuery` is for querying `Entities` based on `Field values`. If you aren't querying over fields, the savvy developer will save the extra overhead and use a `db_select()`. FYI an `EntityFieldQuery` uses a `SelectQuery` (the type of object returned from  `db_select()`) internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Make sure you actually display the results

```
if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  $output = node_view_multiple($nodes);
  drupal_render($output);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The `propertyCondition` method needs a 3 parameter for the matching to work

```
propertyCondition('language', $language->language, '=')
```

Comment: Sorry but that's just not correct - the third parameter to `propertyCondition()` has a default value of `NULL` anyway, which cascades down to an `=` in the `SelectQuery::condition()` method. Adding that third parameter makes zero difference to the query being performed

Comment: Yeah, the function defaults to either `=` or `IN` depending on the value param as an array or string. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyCondition/7